# React Native TransformError

Tags: react-native

I just created a react native app and did an npm install after that. I tried running the app after npm install, and this showed in my emulator. How do i fix this guys?

[image]

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: I havent put any codes yet

Comment: Restart the server by `react-native start`

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730336/4087540 See if that answer solves the issue.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730336/4087540 See if that answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with "babel-preset-react-native", I removed  version 3.0.0 and installed it to 2.1.0.

1. Remove folder babel-preset-react-native inside node_modules
2. Change the version of babel-preset-react-native in package.json to 2.1.0
3. Run `npm install`