# react native transform - error couldn't find preset "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I started ejecting expo, after so much struggle I could able to solve all build issues.
When I run the app using 'sudo react-native run-android' I started getting following error

Error:

```
The development server returned response code 500
Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  
0.0% (0/1), failed.
error: bundling failed: "TransformError: 

/Development/SourceCode/MobileApp/index.android.js: 
Couldn't find preset \"babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support\" relative to directory \"/Development/SourceCode/MobileApp\""
```

I tried almost all possible fixes given in github and SO

1. uninstalling latest version of babel-preset-react-native and re-installing     sudo yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
2. Clear cache Yarn Cache, npm cache
3. deleting build folder, deleting npm modules and reinstall all modules
4. Few people fixed the issue by removing watchman, but I am not using watchman at all.
5. Adding .babelrc mentioning decorator-support for preset as follows, this fix also didn't work.

**`.babelrc`** file looks like this

```
    {
      "presets": [
        "react-native",
        "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
      ],
      "env": {
        "development": {
          "plugins": [
            "transform-react-jsx-source"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

None of those fixes worked for me. using `babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0` also didn't fix the issue because that was the major fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use normal babel preset 0 as per: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0

so

```
"presets": ["react-native", "stage-0"]
```

Comment: thanks but I just used "presets": ["react-native"] and it worked. Can you let me know what is the stage-0 here ? is it required ?

Comment: JavaScript has some proposals for new features that are not yet finalized. They are separated into 5 states (0 to 4). As proposals gain more traction and are more likely to be accepted into the standard they proceed through the various stages, finally being accepted into the standard at stage 4.

In Babel, these changes are bundled in 4 different presets:
babel-preset-stage-0,
babel-preset-stage-1,
babel-preset-stage-2,
babel-preset-stage-3.  It is not mandatory to add, depends on your use case.

Comment: @Sadanand judging by what you tried in your question you needed a decorator support, that is currently experimental. `stage-0` preset ads it and a lot of other js proposals that are currently work in progress / idea level. If it works fro you without it, it means you are not using any of these features, so just `react-native` preset will be good :)

Comment: do I have to add a new file with ".babelrc"?

Comment: @SatishMavani yep, at the root of your react native project if you don't already have one, you will also need to npm install babel-preset-react native and include it as demonstrated above.

Comment: thanks, @llja is it needed for android or ios?  I run that command and still don't see any file like .babelrc FYI I am trying to build iOS app using android.

Comment: @SatishMavani you need to create babelrc yourself, this is for react native project's javascript side, i.e. it allows you to use decorators that are not even part of js at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create .babelrc file in root of you project with following content if you cany use old version of React Native:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did use Expo in your project,

try:

1. $ `cd your_project`
2. $ `nano .babelrc` (Or any editor that you wants)
3. Copy and paste #A

If you didn't have .babelrc in your project, then:

1. `$ cd your_project`
2. `touch .babelrc`
3. copy and paste #A

#### #A

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```